# Inefficiency of readonly fields

Tags: c#

Earlier today I was doing some investigation and came across this article:

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/

Which states that readonly fields are in fact inefficient, even if you have to look at a micro-optimization point of view.

Are there any other studies that confirm this?
Should we be using readonly fields or is there an alternative that allows us to achieve the same results without losing efficiency in runtime?

Comment: Do note that the article states: "in a 64-bit CLR, but no RyuJIT". The findings are implementation dependent and subject to change.

Comment: I really appreciate you using the word investigate instead of research. I see countless people who think google-searching something is the same as researching it.

Answer (score 10):

> Should we be using readonly fields

Yes.

Because it adds self-documentation and self-verification to our code. The benefits of expressing the intent of a field far outweigh any (loss of) micro optimization.

Comment: @Wouter, Jon does say *This isn’t an optimization I’d recommend in general.* Hold your horses.

Comment: It is a compile time solution for a runtime problem @WouterHuysentruit. Seems a good optimization to me.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit "*this is the first time that it’s had a practical impact on me*" if it measurably affects you then it's no longer premature optimization. C# is certainly suited for applications requiring solid performance and besides -- the blogpost is about a C# library to start with. The answer is not to "just not make that library" at all.

Comment: Also in the article: _I regard Noda Time as a sort of "system level" library_ which is the correct reason for this kind of optimization. The Fx library itself often goes against some best-practices for the sake of performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is c# “readonly” really inefficient?

It depends on what kind of efficency is your concern.

Usually time spent on maintenance is the concern.

If you want to improve your code in nanoseconds or for high complexity situations, lower level languages can be options.. Because object orientation is firstly for maintainability, I think.

Try [assembly](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/) :)

Answer (score 0):

> Should we be using readonly fields

In the words of Jon Skeet, the highest rated SO poster, and from the post you linked

> This isn’t an optimization I’d recommend in general. Most code really doesn’t need to be micro-optimized this hard...

And Jon said, let there be `readonly` fields.

> is there an alternative that allows us to achieve the same results without losing efficiency in runtime?

Although this isn't the same as a `readonly` field, another similar option is to use a property with only a `get` accessor, and no `set` accessor.  This will **NOT** allow you to set a value during construction (like you can with a readonly field) but the value still cannot be modified after that.  If setting the property internally to the class is acceptable, then you can also have a `private set` accessor.